# How to use getFullYear, getMonth and getDate in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, get

I know how to use `getFullYear();`, `getMonth();` and `getDate();` in JavaScript:

```
$year = ($hFdate.getFullYear());
$month = ($hFdate.getMonth());
$day = ($hFdate.getDate());
```

How can I use these functions in PHP?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/class.datetime.php#118608

Comment: @TsV how datetime will help the OP?

Comment: What is `$hFdate`?

Comment: D. Dimitrov easy

Comment: make hFdate a \DateTime object then $hfDate->format('Y'); $hfDate->format('m'); $hfDate->format('Y-m-d');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming your $hFdate is a string of date

```
        $hFdate="2018-09-14";
        $year = date('Y',strtotime($hFdate));
        $month = date('m',strtotime($hFdate));
        $year = date('d',strtotime($hFdate));
```